# Donde se utilizan las tablas en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo la tabla con nombre `AR_CLIENTES` y necesito saber si esta tabla se utiliza en alguna view, function o stored procedure.

¿Existe una consulta para saberlo ?

Answer (score 2):

Dos consultas que me ayudan mucho para revisar la pertenencia de tablas en Store Procedures, Views y Functions, son:

[sys.sql_modules](http://sys.sql_modules%20(Transact-SQL))

> Devuelve una fila para cada objeto que es un módulo definido con
>   lenguaje SQL en SQL Server, incluido de forma nativa compila función
>   escalar definida por el usuario. Los objetos del tipo P, RF, V, TR,
>   FN, IF, TF y R tienen un módulo SQL asociado. Los valores
>   predeterminados independientes, objetos del tipo D, también incluyen
>   una definición de módulo SQL en esta vista. Para obtener una
>   descripción de estos tipos, vea la tipo columna en el sys.objects
>   vista de catálogo.

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(o.SCHEMA_ID), o.Name, o.[type]
FROM sys.sql_modules m
INNER JOIN sys.objects o
    ON o.object_id = m.object_id
WHERE m.definition like '%AR_CLIENTES%'
GO
```

y en segundo lugar [ROUTINES (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/routines-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> Devuelve una fila por cada procedimiento almacenado y función a los
>   que puede tener acceso el usuario actual en la base de datos actual.
>   Las columnas que describen el valor devuelto solo se aplican a
>   funciones. Para procedimientos almacenados, estas columnas serán NULL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%AR_CLIENTES%'
```

Espero te ayude a solucionar tu necesidad.